# spark MetricsSystem registerSource failed

Tags: java, apache-spark

when I running spark job, I encountered the following problems.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSource(MetricsSystem.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 34
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.apply(ResizableArray.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.apply(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.segmentLength(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:195)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.segmentLength(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.indexWhere(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:204)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.indexWhere(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.GenSeqLike$class.indexOf(GenSeqLike.scala:145)
        at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.indexOf(Seq.scala:41)
        at scala.collection.GenSeqLike$class.indexOf(GenSeqLike.scala:129)
        at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.indexOf(Seq.scala:41)
        at scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike$class.$minus$eq(BufferLike.scala:127)
        at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractBuffer.$minus$eq(Buffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.removeSource(MetricsSystem.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1412)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:421)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

when my task retried more than four times, the job was killed, error msg like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 24 in stage 389.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 24.3 in stage 389.0 (TID 54433, 10.160.140.73, executor 87): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSource(MetricsSystem.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2064)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2085)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2104)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2129)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:1000)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:999)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at org.qihoo.cluster.XgbostCluster.cluster(XgbostCluster.java:316)
        at org.qihoo.cluster.XgbostCluster.start(XgbostCluster.java:106)
        at org.qihoo.App.main(App.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSource(MetricsSystem.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think it may be same cause with this jira [Race condition while registering source in MetricsSystem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34934), but I am not sure.I wonder if I have some way to resolve this problem.
my spark version is 2.4.5 and i can not change its version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding some synchronized operation on MetricsSystem.scala with the instruction of the [spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/metrics/MetricsSystem.scala) and building a new spark-core.jar. Then I use the new jar to submit the task which can run perfectly.

params:

--jars spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar 
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=./spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=./spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar \